# Hyperledger fabric private channel does it create new separate ledger

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Assume that we have 3 organisation org1, org2, org3, each organisation has 2 peers means total 6 peers and each organisation consist of orderer total 3 ordered.

we create 2 channel...

First is
**channelAll**, In which all the orgs and peers are connected.

Second channel we create **channel23** this channel between org2 and org3. Now my question is

```
1. when i send transaction on channelAll all the peers means total 6 peers and 3 orderer is update the ledger, saying that transaction valid and its create the new block number 1.
2. when i send the transaction to channel23, does all total 6 peers and 3 ordrer also get updated or org2 and org3 with their peers means total 4 peers, which is connect to channel23 only this will get update the ledger and create the new block 2.
3. If only org2 and org3 in channel channel23 is updated means its creating the new block which will not know to org1 then how does blockchain work, already org1 has missed the block.
```

Actually i am bit confused here, could some suggest me how does block create if i have private channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Private data concept is implemented to avoid create multiple channels for privacy between organizations
```

> One channel can achieve privacy between organizations
>
> Ex: channelName: mychannel Orgs: Org1, Org2, Org3
>
> can want to create ledger twp types 1) common to all  2) private b/w
>   org1 & org2
>
> So you can create collections  see detailed tutorial [here](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/tutorial-private-data.html#targetText=Starting%20in%20v1.2%2C%20Fabric,Using%20Private%20Data%20in%20Fabric.)

Coming to your questions:

when private data is implemented it will not create multiple ledgers, one channel has one blockchain

private data will be stored in unauthorized org peers as a hash & authorized peers as normal data in order to validate so data will not be stored in unauthorized peers

Comment: thank you !.Assume, that org 1,org 2, org 3 already consist of 10 transaction and now orderer and peers are at block number 12 of all three organisation, Now one more  transaction create through channel23 that org2 and org3, so now what will the block number in orderer and peers of all 3 organisation and what will the block number in orderer and peers in org2 and org2, i am confused so could you please explain

Comment: regardless of either private data or normal data all organization committing peers will receive the block. So the block height is the same in all organizations. the only change is unauthorized peers will not have the data instead hash of the data will be present

Comment: make sense, thank you, does orderer will have the database to keep track of blocks.

Comment: Yes, Since orderer creates the blocks it also will store the ledger

Comment: is it possible to query the orderer ledger and peer ledger, without using the chain code ?

Comment: Anytime @fama happy hyperledger fabric!!

Answer (score 0):

Each channel is its separate independent blockchain, so org1 doesn't see the blocks in channel23.

Comment: thank you for replay, i am bit confused here,If org1 does not see the blocks created in channel23, then how org1  orderer keep track of blocks of all the transaction and send the transaction to validate to  all the 6 peers?                                                             does the db of all orderer and  the peers are differently, then how blocks keep track of previous block

Comment: In Raft, a channel can contain only a subset of all orderers, so channel23 doesn't have orderer of org1.